# find command unpredictable behaviour?

Tags: command-line, unix, find, disk-space, shell-script

I am working on a remote machine,the disk space on the HP-UNIX machine was 96% so  I was going to reduce the disk space by zipping some `"*.extract.sys"` files.

```
$find . "*extract.sys" -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

Now the above commad is supposed to show the files with extension "extract.sys" but 
 instead I am getting files with extension extract, some directories, and files with other extension.

why is this happening?
I hope that its not because of the disk space.

EDIT: Is there another way around or I am doing some mistake/missing something

Comment: find is recursive, so for starters, remove the recursive (r) option from ls.

Comment: I worked for me  before but today its not working anyway I tried removing the recursive(r) option but still the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `-name` option before `*extract.sys`; otherwise it will look *in* directories matching `*extract.sys` (in addition to `.`) rather that looking *for* files matching `*extract.sys`.  Also you should use single quotes around `*extract.sys` instead of double quotes so that the shell will not treat it as a wildcard.  (You only want `find` to treat it as a wildcard, not the shell.)

```
find . -name '*extract.sys' -exec ...
```